# How can we secure cookie by using secure flag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, setcookie

I am storing token in cookie and want to secure by secure flag but when I console then secure flag is not showing.

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue) {

  document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + "secure";
}
```

document.cookie>
"token1=xxxxxxxxxxxxx ; token2=yyyyyyyyy;  "

Comment: You can check in *Application* tab under Developer tools to check if it's set as secured or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll not print *Secure* when you do `document.cookie` but this can be verified by navigating to *Application* tab under developer console and *Cookies* under *Storage*

> Application -> Storage -> Cookies -> (Your site)

In the right side you can see all the cookies set for the site, there you can check `Secure` flag whether it's set or not.

Below I'm attaching the screenshots for the same

[image]
[image]

Hope this helps.